# Does append() create a copy of the arguments or append the actual argument's reference to the list?

Tags: python, append

When I run

```
x = [0, 1]
y = [2, 3]
x.append(y)
x[2][1] = 4
print y
```

it prints out

```
[2, 4]
```

So, basically, is it appending the reference of the argument to the list? not a copy that is totally unrelated to the argument?

Comment: Python names and list contents are references, and unless documented otherwise, no copies are created when you pass a name to a method. This applies just as much to `list.append()` as to any other call; `list.append()` adds a reference to the list, not a copy.

Comment: You may also be interested in reading [this excellent article on Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).